# What to do on Hetzner/Robot 'The desired vServer action failed.'

Tags: linux-vserver

I want to restart my vServer @ Hetzner through their Robot web-interface. All actions (start, stop, reset) won't work and give "The desired vServer action failed.". The robot states that the server is turned off. I can't reach my web services There's no hint what's going on so far. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes: Contact Hetzner. They should be able to help you. How do you imagine that *we* could do that?

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! You're question should be directed at your service provider, they understand their system better and you will get better help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply, but effectiv: Call Hetzner's support. Since this is a special software, only they can help you.